# Tokenize a command string

Tags: python, regex

I have string like this:

```
command ". / * or any other char like this" some_param="string param" some_param2=50
```

I want to tokenize this string into:

```
command
". / * or any other char like this"
some_param="string param"
some_param2=50
```

I know it's possible to split with spaces but these parameters can also be seperated by commas, like:

```
command ". / * or any other char like this", some_param="string param", some_param2=50
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
\w+\=?\"?.+\"?
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> x='command ". / * or any other char like this" some_param="string param" some_param2=50'
>>>
>>> re.findall('\w+\=\d+|\w+\="[^"]+"|"[^"]+"|\w+',x)
['command', '". / * or any other char like this"', 'some_param="string param"', 'some_param2=50']
>>>
```

Comment: I tried to change your regex with adding '|\w+="{3}[^"]+"{3}' after that to handle paramname="""paramvalue""" type parameters too but it didn't work. That's strange.

Comment: @pocoa, I guess, you need to add that in front of others like `\w+="{3}[^"]+"{3}|\w+=\d+|\w+="[^"]+"|"[^"]+"|\w+`

Comment: ah ok, I was writing comment to mention same thing, while you did it work.

Answer (score 3):

The stdlib module shlex is designed for parsing shell-like command syntax:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> s = 'command ". / * or any other char like this" some_param="string param" some_param2=50'
>>> shlex.split(s)
['command', '. / * or any other char like this', 'some_param=string param', 'some_param2=50']
```

The only difference from your desired result is that the quoted string is returned as the string value, not as the quoted string literal.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice tool. But it's not working when these parameters are separated by commas.